# Printing page html from PDF (external)

Tags: html, pdf, media-queries

[HERE](http://studiodentisticocova.com/relazioni-psico-dentali/) there is a page that maybe the visitors would print. If you try to print it's a mess. I know that there is proper media queries to do that but I think it takes a a lot of work. 
So my question is this: is there a way to open a external/existing PDF when I decide to print the page? 
I mean when I click the print botton of the browser, not a custom botton on the page.
Thanks guys :)

Comment: I don't know if it's possible but you can take a look to this library : HTML2PDF http://html2pdf.fr/

Comment: I think it's obviously impossible for a page to override the print button. It would be like overriding the "home" or "previous page" button to do something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible to do this that way. But really, don't be afraid of media types.

Here are some ideas:

1 - BEST) Style media = print: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
</head>
```

And Use another style sheet for printer media. This is the best solution, and this style can be really minimal.

2) Use some kind of converter (html to PDF) and convert each page that You want to 'be printable'. Then place Print icon somewhere on the page which is the link to pdf version. You can also map CTRL + P using JQuery for example, and run download pdf dialog.
 It is not a good solution in my opinion, every new page = total mess and converrting, and... Not worth. It should be done automatically.

3) I don't know what kind of files are U using, but if it is simple html, U can run bash script using PHP that converts the page using for example html2pdf converter on the fly. Then, U can make the printer friendly version icon, and redirect someone to a php script which make pdf and display it. But here also You need a new icon, and File print doesn't work.

So the solution 1 is the best I think...

Hope it helps :)

PS. Media types are not so time consuming. You make only few changes. Navigation display hidden, font size, img display and that's really all. And You can do it once. Converting must be done multi, multi, multiple times :). If You have any questions about 2, and 3 solution write, I can help to make a sketch of them :).